# Fail to upload docx file in OnlyOffice using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, onlyoffice

We have integrated the OnlyOffice editor in our application. I want to upload a .docx file from my PC to OnlyOffice server, so that we can use it later for editing. I am giving a POST request to the server using formdata, but it is not working. Following is my javascript code:

```
app.post('/topic/:id/upload', (req, res) => {
  docManager.init(__dirname, req, res);
  //docManager.storagePath(''); // mkdir if not exist
  const userIp = docManager.curUserHostAddress();
  const uploadDir = `./public/${configServer.get('storageFolder')}/${userIp}`;
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = uploadDir;
  form.keepExtensions = true;

  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    const file = files.uploadedFile;
    file.name = docManager.getCorrectName(file.name);

    if (configServer.get('maxFileSize') < file.size || file.size <= 0) {
      fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      res.write('{ "error": "File size is incorrect"}');
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    const exts = [].concat(
      configServer.get('viewedDocs'),
      configServer.get('editedDocs'),
      configServer.get('convertedDocs')
    );
    const curExt = fileUtility.getFileExtension(file.name);

    if (exts.indexOf(curExt) === -1) {
      fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      res.write('{ "error": "File type is not supported"}');
      res.end();
      return;
    }

    fs.rename(file.path, `${uploadDir}/${file.name}`, (err2) => {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      if (err2) {
        res.write(`{ "error": "${err2}"}`);
      } else {
        res.write(`{ "filename": "${file.name}"}`);

        const userid = req.query.userid ? req.query.userid : 'uid-1';
        const firstname = req.query.firstname ? req.query.firstname : 'Jonn';
        const lastname = req.query.lastname ? req.query.lastname : 'Smith';

        docManager.saveFileData(file.name, userid, `${firstname} ${lastname}`);
        docManager.getFileData(file.name, docManager.curUserHostAddress());
      }
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

At the beginning, in form.parse() call, there is a files array. This array is coming in as empty. And hence, I'm getting error as:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Following is my component code:

```
uploadFile(topicId: any, files: File[]) {
    this.fileToUpload = files[0];
    let apiUrl = "/topic/" + topicId + "/upload";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.fileToUpload);
    this.ooApiService.postUrl(apiUrl, data, {headers})
     .toPromise()
     .catch(
       (error: any) => this.handleError(error)
     );
  }
```

HTML code:

```
  <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input class="chooseFile" id="uploadedFile" type="file" [disabled]="isChosen" #fileInput (change)="chooseImage(fileInput.files)"/>
    <button *ngIf="userCanEditDetails" md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="uploadFile(topic.id, fileInput.files)">
      {{ "Upload file" | translate }}
    </button>
  </form>
```

I am invoking this POST request from my client application which is in angular2, from there I am selecting and passing a file as a formdata.
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to pay your attention to the fact that you are using an integration example.
This application is used to demonstrate document editors functions and it is not recommended for using in a production environment.
According to the information provided by you the document just wasn't sent to ONLYOFFICE server

Please note that the default version of the test example is totally functional, to understand why it doesn't work after your changes we also need to analyze the client part. Please send us the code how you upload the file into the document manager.
You probably do not sent the content with file details when sending a POST request.